# HTTP Live Streaming to Apple TV using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, http-live-streaming, apple-tv

I am developing a web application for iPad/iPhone which will allow users to select from a list of local videos.  The web application is built on top of Ruby on Rails and will allow me to circumvent App Store requirements (keep that in mind).

Users will select a video from a list in the web app.  The videos are located on a local server.  I am wondering if it is possible to then, based on the user's selection, push the video to an Apple TV nearby.

I am wondering if it is possible to have Rails do the backend processing of requests from users, such as queuing a video, preparing it for HTTP Live Streaming, and then streaming it to an Apple TV device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of sharing knowledge, there's a great starting point over here at:

www.github.com/elcuervo/airplay

The creator's name is Bruno Aguirre and he loves feedback.  This gem should help you stream from a server in Ruby on Rails to an Apple TV.